# Uni-Directional Stretchable Elastomers

Tags: materials

Are there any fabrics available in today’s time which can stretch in one direction only and behave completely rigid in the perpendicular direction ?

[image]

Or does any Materials Science expert know about any on-going research in this area ?

I particularly wanted to know the way in which one might go about manufacturing something like this.

So, if such a fabric is imagined to be made up of perpendicularly intersecting fibres, one of which is stretchable while the other is not, like criss-crossing rubber & fibreglass fibres, for instance, what would be the way to make something like this ?

[image]

Comment: I could fab an equivalent by tying a bunch of metal rods together with elastic strings -- rods in y-axis, elastics in x-axis.  Problem with "fabric" is that implies a material which flexes (folds) easily in both axes, so now you're looking for a material that's flexible but not extensible.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes. Exactly so. Sorry for not being more elaborate.

Comment: @RedHelmet so edit your question so it is clearer, expecting people to trawl through comments to piece together your meaning ....

Comment: @SolarMike ok done.

Answer (score 1):

If you calender a rubber with some thin steel cords in the calendered direction you could achieve this.

Edit:
For those who are unfamiliar with [calenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calender), they are "a series of hard pressure rollers used to finish or smooth a sheet of material such as paper, textiles, or plastics".

Do not confuse calenders (with an ers ending), which are rollers, with calendars (with an ars ending) which is a time keeping device.